# Vargrantfile - Ruby - unexpected end of file

Tags: ruby, vagrant, vagrantfile

I am new to ruby. I was trying to modify existing Vargrantfile which is of ruby syntax.
I have below

```
def has_program(program)
  ENV['PATH'].split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR).any? do |directory|
    File.executable?(File.join(directory, program.to_s))
  end
end 

is_exist = has_program("some-command")
puts is_exist
$my_script = %{
if is_exist == false
  if ! some-command status; then
    #Do some staff
  fi
end
# do some staff
}

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

   node.vm.provision "shell", inline: $my_script
end
```

Then while running `vagrant up --provision` I am getting below error

```
syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Can you please let me know what error I am doing?

With regards,
-M-

Answer (score 1):

This is a syntax error but not one in your Ruby code as such. It's an unfinished statement in the shell code that you're executing from the Ruby script.

This can happen if you leave a block unclosed. The parser expects to find its end but encounters the end of the script instead.

Let's look at the part where you're executing a shell command

```
$my_script = %{
if is_exist == false
  if ! some-command status; then
    #Do some staff
  fi
end
# do some staff
}
```

Now, let's strip the Ruby parts you have around it. The assignment `$my_script =` is still Ruby code. The part in curly braces is a string literal in the [% notation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation) that you later execute as a shell script using Vagrant's [`inline`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html#inline)... However, it appears that you're switching back to Ruby syntax before ending the string literal.

What the interpreter parses as a shell script is this part:

```
if is_exist == false
  if ! some-command status; then
    #Do some staff
  fi
end
# do some staff
```

Notice that the whole outer `if` expression uses Ruby's `if` syntax. It's not a valid shell command, hence the error.

I'm not sure what the semantics of this expression are in your case but you need to convert it to a shell `if` or move it outside the string literal you're passing to Vagrant using the `inline` option. On a side note, the logic inside seems strange. You're calling `some-command` if `has_program("some-command")` returns false. But that's a separate story :)

Comment: thanks a lot for explanation, I have fixed it now. ```if is_exist == false``` was for testing.